# Sculpting problems, not enough faces?

Tags: sculpting, artifacts

I've just started trying out the sculpting tools in blender. I first followed this sculpting basics tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uVpwivEl_6o
and am now trying to sculpt a leaf shape.

I started out with a bezier curve for the leaf outline, which I then converted to a mesh, then extruded to give it a bit of depth and then cut out some holes, this got me an object which looks like this:

[image: Object which I'm trying to sculpt]

Now the problem is that when I try to follow the tutorial and use the multiresolution modifier, I get something which looks like this:

[image: Object with multiresolution modifier]

Or if I try to directly use one of the sculpting tools on the leaf objects, for example to make a crease down the middle, it looks like this:

[image: Object when using sculpt tools]

Obviously this isn't what I'm going for at all.

Now I'm thinking it might be that the faces on the top side of the leaf might be too few / not at all in the shape that I want to modify, my question is, how do I change that? Shouldn't the multiresolution modifier add more faces?
Or should I have created the basic shape in a different way?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: The linked tutorial is not suitable for what you are going for. The two major problems with your mesh are 1) that it is not going to be evenly subdivided by the modifier and 2) that it has ngons instead of quads. You might achieve a better result when using dynamic topology. Search for tutorials with "dyntopo" or "dynamic topology" instead.